# Specialization of template member functions of a non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, member-functions

I would like to define the explicit specialization of a template function in a cpp file. Is that possible? To be more concrete, I have the following code, which compiles without errors:

```
//class.h
class myclass
{
public:
    /* Constructor */
    myclass();
    /* Trigger fcn */
    template<typename T> T Trigger(T rn);

private:
    /* Specializations of the templated Trigger(...) function */
    template<> int Trigger<int>(int rn)
    {
        int_do(rn);
    }
    template<> double Trigger<double>(double rn)
    {
        double_do(rn);
    }
}
```

However, I having the definitions in the header file looks weird for me, so I would like to separate the definitions from the declarations, something like this:

```
//class.h
class myclass
{
public:
    /* Constructor */
    myclass();
    /* Trigger fcn */
    template<typename T> T Trigger(T rn);

private:
    /* Specializations of the templated Trigger(...) function */
    template<> int Trigger<int>(int rn);
    template<> double Trigger<double>(double rn);   
}
```

and:

```
//class.cpp
/* Specializations of the templated Trigger(...) function */
template<> int myclass::Trigger<int>(int rn)
{
    int_do(rn);
}
template<> double myclass::Trigger<double>(double rn)
{
    double_do(rn);
}
```

Is there any way to to this?

Comment: It looks weird is not a good enough reason IMO. There's no method to do this which doesn't involve some compromise, so I would just get used to it.

Comment: Your template definition needs to stay in the header file, but you can have the functions declared the way you have, outside the class {} block definition (just still in the .h file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare template function outside the class declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047663/how-do-i-declare-template-function-outside-the-class-declaration)

Comment: Neither code even compiles... You can only write specializations in the namespace enclosing the class. For both: GCC: `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class myclass'`. Clang: `error: explicit specialization of 'Trigger' in class scope`. Are you using MSVC?

Comment: I *think* you're mushing *explicit instantiation* and *specialization* into the same basket. They're not the same. The latter usually provides alternative implementation, the former provides a mechanism for assigning an instantiation to a specific translation unit. If you want to specialize while also assigning to a specific compilation unit, see Mike's answer below.

Comment: @gx_ yes, I am using VisualStudio 9.0, and the former code compiles in my PC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your only error is declaring the specialisations inside the class. Declare them in the header, but outside the class:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass();
    template<typename T> T Trigger(T rn);
};

/* Specializations of the templated Trigger(...) function */
template<> int myclass::Trigger<int>(int rn);
template<> double myclass::Trigger<double>(double rn);
```

and then you can define them in a source file, exactly as you have done.

Note that your first snippet doesn't compile (unless your compiler has a non-standard extension), since the specialisations can't be declared inside the class.

Comment: Thanks Mike, now it compiles. BTW, my previous code was compiling with VisualStudio 9.0, I do not know whether it uses a non-standard extension or not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to earlier answer regarding the positioning of the specialization:

You can define template functions in a .cpp file. This also means that they can only be instantiated within this translation object/file. 
In your case, the partial specialization is declared in the .h, and other compilation units will expect their existence.

For example in 
file tmp.h:

```
#include <iostream>
class T {
public:
  template <typename T> void foo(const T& t)
  {
    std::cout << "generic foo" << std::endl;
  }
};
// forward declaration of specialization
template<> void T::foo(const double& t);
```

file tmp.cpp:

```
#include "tmp.h"

template <> void T::foo(const double& t)
{
  std::cout << "double foo" << std::endl;
}
```

file main.cpp:

```
#include "tmp.h"
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  T t;
  t.foo(1.0); 
  t.foo(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Now compiling both .cpp files will work fine:

```
g++ main.cpp tmp.cpp -o tmp
./tmp
double foo
generic foo
```

without the definition of the specialization:

```
g++ main.cpp -o tmp
/tmp/ccpCJr3B.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `void T::foo<double>(double const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It's not what I was asking, but very useful. Thanks!